# RIDE installation problems

Tags: python, robotframework

While installing RIDE 1.2, I got the below error on final screen.

```
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

After finishing the RIDE installation, I double clicked the RIDE icon, but RIDE is not getting launched.
Can someone please help me in this?

Note: I have Python 2.7.6 pre-installed on my Win7 32-bit machine.

Comment: what does python -V tell you? what operating system you are using? How did yoy try to install RIDE?

Comment: @Harri It has shown the following -> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    python -V
NameError: name 'python' is not defined

Comment: Did you run that python -V from windows command prompt or python shell?

Comment: @Harri From python shell.

Comment: From Windows cmd prompt --> C:\Users\Administrator>python -v
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: it means that python is not in your PATH environment variable. in order to install ride (and use robot framework) it must be there. chech out the official installation instruction https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/wiki/Installation-Instructions

Comment: @Harri As you told, I have set python directory to PATH system variable. Now cmd 'python' has shown the Python version. But even after this, RIDE is not getting launched(Note: Before installing RIDE, I already installed robotframework-2.8.3.win32.exe). Pls help me.

Comment: did you follow the installation instructions and especially the start up part https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/wiki/Installation-Instructions#wiki-start-up

Comment: @Harri Thank you for the link. I did not install the "wxPython", now I installed wxPython and RIDE opened successfully [As per the instructions, RIDE requires wxPython].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed **wxPython** and now RIDE is getting launched successfully.

As per the instructions given in [link](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/wiki/Installation-Instructions), RIDE's GUI is implemented using wxPython toolkit.

Comment: Yes, after having Python, IronPython and robotframework you really need to install WXPython to have the RIDE installed correctly. Moreover, as per your question, you can always kill the RIDE process killed via TaskBar.